# Send Java JMX metrics running in ECS to CloudWatch with CollectD

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmx, collectd

I have a Java application running as a container in an ECS cluster. I want to be able to get JMX metrics and send them to AWS CloudWatch.
Initially, I was using this article as a reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/deliver-java-jmx-statistics-to-amazon-cloudwatch-using-the-cloudwatch-agent-and-collectd/

However, I noticed that it runs everything on a single EC2 instance. I have read that ECS integrates with CloudWatch Insights but I can't get it to work.
I also tried using CollectD only, but I'm only getting logs saying that plugins have been initialised.

I run the application with the following flags:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I also have the following config for CollectD(sidecar):

```
LoadPlugin network
<Plugin network>
    <Server "127.0.0.1" "25826">
    </Server>
</Plugin>
LoadPlugin java
<Plugin java>
  JVMArg "-Djava.class.path=/usr/share/collectd/java/collectd-api.jar:/usr/share/collectd/java/generic-jmx.jar"
  LoadPlugin "org.collectd.java.GenericJMX"

  <Plugin "GenericJMX">
    <MBean "Memory">
      ObjectName "java.lang:type=Memory"
      InstancePrefix "java"
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_memory_heapmemoryusage_"
        Table true
        Attribute "HeapMemoryUsage"
      </Value>
    </MBean>

    <MBean "OperatingSystem">
      ObjectName "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"
      InstancePrefix "java"
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_operatingsystem_freephysicalmemorysize"
        Attribute "FreePhysicalMemorySize"
      </Value>
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_operatingsystem_freeswapsizespace"
        Attribute "FreeSwapSpaceSize"
      </Value>
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_operatingsystem_committedvirtualmemorysize"
        Attribute "CommittedVirtualMemorySize"
      </Value>
    </MBean>

    <MBean "Threading">
      ObjectName "java.lang:type=Threading"
      InstancePrefix "java"
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_threading_threadcount"
        Attribute "ThreadCount"
      </Value>
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_threading_daemonthreadcount"
        Attribute "DaemonThreadCount"
      </Value>
    </MBean>

    <MBean "ClassLoading">
      ObjectName "java.lang:type=ClassLoading"
      InstancePrefix "java"
      <Value>
        Type "gauge"
        InstancePrefix "java_lang_classloading_loadedclasscount"
        Attribute "LoadedClassCount"
      </Value>
    </MBean>

    <Connection>
      Host "127.0.0.1"
      ServiceURL "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:9999/jmxrmi"
      Collect "Memory"
      Collect "OperatingSystem"
      Collect "Threading"
      Collect "ClassLoading"
    </Connection>
  </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?I need to get the metrics configured in CollectD config file.